# Adding django model default values after creation

Tags: django, django-models, default-value

I created a model similar to the following:

```
class Pick(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    week = models.IntegerField()
    result = models.IntegerField()
```

This worked great until I wanted to add a default value to result. I made the following change:

```
result = models.IntegerField(default=3)
```

I still get a 'Field required' error when trying to add a new Pick.  I don't want to destroy the database, if possible.  I tried adding a default value straight into mysql but I think the model default values are checked in code before going to the db.  What's the best way to get this default value working?

EDIT:
ok, so I feel like a moron; I don't know what was going on but I was modifying the model in my IDE and nothing was working.  I tried modifying the help_text (which I didn't include in my examples) and that wasn't changing either.  I eventually went to the command line and realized that I hadn't been changing the file at all.  I still have no idea what happened, as I have been making all changes through the IDE.  So it appears that I am just crazy after all.  Thanks for all the comments as it helped me search for a solution outside the normalities of the code.

Comment: What you've described *should* work. What gives you the “field required” error? Is it the admin? Forms? Custom code? And if it's custom code, could you post that?

Comment: Doesn't the model have to have blank=True for forms to work with blank values and nullable=True so it can use the default value?  May be compleltely wrong as I don't have tins of Django experience and am not at a computer to look it up.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and look into Django-South.

Comment: It's failing in the admin section, specifically telling me "This field is required."  I have added blank=True and required=False and it's still failing.  I am running syncdb after all of this as well. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: result = models.IntegerField(default=3,required=False) doesn't work ?

Comment: +1 for the django-south recommendation, I actually looked into that for a work project about a month ago.  This question is more out of curiosity as to why this isn't working.

Comment: So I currently have:     result = models.IntegerField(default=3, required=False, blank=True

Comment: Model fields do not have a ``required`` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add 'required=False' to a specific field on a form you are using?

Comment: I did try adding that after your suggestion but I'm still getting the error.